# What does my client mean by a '100.000 DPI, lossless vector 3D' logo?

Tags: client-relations, terminology

My client sent me this:

> I'd like a logo for myself, must be 100.000 DPI, lossless vector 3D printed in gold.

I totally don't understand his request? Please explain things to me. First client ever.

Comment: The best move would be to ask the client. Telling that you don't understand shows you are willing to learn and want to avoid mistakes, while pretending to understand has a high risk of your work mismatching the client's wishes.

Comment: Right! Do you think it's best to meet or just email?

Comment: I think you should to ask your client. Vector images have no DPI. So, if the client wants a vector logo, there's no need to worry about that at least.

Comment: Is your client called Donald something?

Comment: @BillyKerr alrighty, so what is different about victor logos? i never heard of it

Comment: Read this - [raster versus vector](https://www.printcnx.com/resources-and-support/addiational-resources/raster-images-vs-vector-graphics/)

Comment: Tell him that you're happy to take on the assignment, but you'll have to send him the printed logo by e-mail, and the payment is $100,000 in cash paid into your credit card by cheque.

Answer (score 5):

To tell you the truth

- if this is a real question and not a joke
- and if your client is really asking that, again, no joking

This is simply an **ignorant request**.

---

> must be 100.000 DPI

- A logo should be designed resolution independent.
- DPI is a unit to measure the printer capability. 3200 dpi is a really, really, really small dot. 100,000 dpi does not exist. (using a decimal dot, if that is what that has no sense either)

> lossless vector

What is losless vector? that does not exist either.

> printed in gold.

This is a case specific application, you need to clarify if it is real gold (gold plate), hot-stamping (simulating shiny gold) or golden ink (golden dust applied to transparent base)

> 3D printed in gold

The 3D effect is on the final product? like an engraving? or is it an intrinsic part of it, which would make the one ink hot-stamping application almost impossible to print?

> First client ever

Ouch. That is bad luck... or really good one... can not tell.

---

Getting more serious about this.

You have not done a proper briefing.

Where the logo should be used. On a building, on a letterhead, on the glass on the door of the office

What is the 3D effect needed for? Is it an intrinsic part of the logo or is an adaptation of it.

Is this 3D effect result of the print or manufacturing process, like engraving, construction on metal plates, a carving on a stone?

Is the effect only visual, like for example to be used in a video? https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+logo&rlz=1C1GKLA_enMX664MX664&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimza2XjfLVAhUD1CYKHa5XAOIQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=1012

Will really be printed in gold? Hot stamping and golden plates can not use gradients, only flat solid gold. Ink with dust metallic particles can use gradients but the result is not awsome.

And a big etcétera.

And yes, the 100.000 lossless thing is resolved simply using Illustrator.

The 3D part could be illustrator. But a real 3D logo is rasterized when rendered, so the PPI is back in the game.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a prime case of a client who has heard some nice and spiffy design terms but has no single clue what they are talking about.

'DPI', or dots per inch, is a measure for the amount of ink dots that (two-dimensional) printed work has. DPI is often confused with PPI, pixels per inch, which is the amount of pixels a pixel image has per inch of printed width. Pixel images for standard offset print are usually at least 300 PPI. The catch is that vector is infinitely scalable, and thus has no problems being printed at any number of DPI.

Moreover, vector images are always lossless. You can compress pixel data, but except for some variation in vector format (.ai, .eps or .svg, for example), you can only save vectors lossless.

3D printing in gold is possible as far as I know, but insanely expensive. Not something you would have a beginning designer do.

It's either the client just heard those fancy terms and used them to impress you and themselves, or you are the butt of a joke.

Comment: Simply for the sake of the novice OP, vectors are only infinitely scalable/lossless *if they do not contain embedded raster images*.

Comment: @Yorik to be honest they are not i bet you wont find any vector rendering or rip that does not use a machine precision numeric libraries. So not "infinitely scalable"m just very.

Comment: @joojaa: fair enough, it is just more common to experience someone placing a 100px jpeg into a box using an Ilustrator-like package and then saving it out as vector because "vector is scalable." This is the only reason I got pedantic.

Answer (score -1):

This request is not too unusual.
If someone wants 100 dpi then give it to them. 
Lossless vector is redundant, but lossless vector file types are EPS, .AI plus a couple others which he probably cant use.
3D, unless this is a model or a physical he probably means he wants it to appear 3D, so shadows and highlights etc. This they need to be asked about.
Printed in gold... gold colored ink? actual gold? This also needs clarification.

What I'm suggesting is that when customers ask for dumb but not too weird or difficult things then just give it to them. When a question definitely needs more clarification than ask for it. If they want to be very specific in their request and they're usiing real industry terms then fulfill the request as described and don't try to teach them unless they are making a bad mistake.